# Unexpected exception while loading model: (0, 0)

Tags: pyomo

I just started working with pyomo framework and python. I am trying to solve simple models. And when I formulate the objective function, I receive the following error before when run the code

KeyError: (0, 0)

Here is the formulation of the problem:
[Formulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzkad.png)

And the code:

```
from pyomo.environ import *  

N = 3
M = 4
P = 3
d = {(1, 1): 1.7, (1, 2): 7.2, (1, 3): 9.0, (1, 4): 8.3,
(2, 1): 2.9, (2, 2): 6.3, (2, 3): 9.8, (2, 4): 0.7,
(3, 1): 4.5, (3, 2): 4.8, (3, 3): 4.2, (3, 4): 9.3}

seq = ConcreteModel()
seq.Locations = range(N) #Set N
seq.Customers = range(M) #Set M

seq.x = Var(seq.Locations, seq.Customers, bounds=(0.0, 1.0)) #x[n,m]
seq.y = Var(seq.Locations, within=Binary)

seq.obj=Objective(expr = sum( d[n,m]*seq.x[n,m] for n in seq.Locations for m in seq.Customers))

seq.single_x = ConstraintList()
for m in seq.Customers:
    seq.single_x.add(
        sum(seq.x[n,m] for n in model.Locations ) == 1.0)
    
seq.bound_y = ConstraintList()
for n in seq.Locations:
    for m in seq.Customers:
        seq.bound_y.add( seq.x[n,m] <= seq.y[n] )

seq.num_facilities = Constraint(
    expr=sum( seq.y[n] for n in seq.Locations) == P)
```

What could be an issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key error you are getting is due to the fact that your dictionary `d` doesn't have an entry for [0, 0].

My recommendation is that you bring everything into the model (see my edits below).  That way you can "pretty print" the model, which makes it super easy to troubleshoot while building.

Good luck!

```
from pyomo.environ import *  

N = 3
M = 4
P = 3
d = {(1, 1): 1.7, (1, 2): 7.2, (1, 3): 9.0, (1, 4): 8.3,
(2, 1): 2.9, (2, 2): 6.3, (2, 3): 9.8, (2, 4): 0.7,
(3, 1): 4.5, (3, 2): 4.8, (3, 3): 4.2, (3, 4): 9.3}

seq = ConcreteModel()

###  SETS
seq.Locations = Set(initialize = list(range(1, N+1))) #Set N  # note the capitalization Set, the pyomo type
seq.Customers = Set(initialize = list(range(1, M+1))) #Set M

### PARAMS
seq.d = Param(seq.Locations, seq.Customers, initialize=d)

### VARS
seq.x = Var(seq.Locations, seq.Customers, bounds=(0.0, 1.0)) #x[n,m]
seq.y = Var(seq.Locations, within=Binary)

seq.obj=Objective(expr = sum( seq.d[n,m]*seq.x[n,m] for n in seq.Locations for m in seq.Customers))

seq.single_x = ConstraintList()
for m in seq.Customers:
    seq.single_x.add(
        sum(seq.x[n,m] for n in seq.Locations ) == 1.0)
    
seq.bound_y = ConstraintList()
for n in seq.Locations:
    for m in seq.Customers:
        seq.bound_y.add( seq.x[n,m] <= seq.y[n] )

seq.num_facilities = Constraint(
    expr=sum( seq.y[n] for n in seq.Locations) == P)

seq.pprint()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks really nice! My model runs now smoothly, but I got the following error after getting the results
[    0.21] Applying Pyomo postprocessing actions
[    0.21] Pyomo Finished
errorcode: 0
retval:
What could that be?

Comment: that might be normal...  hard to tell without full context.  Run your model, inspect the solver status and then display your model.  If the solver status is "Optimal" you should be good.  Also, if the answer above answered your question, you can close it out by hitting the check-mark next to it.  If you have problem with solver results, do the above and post a new question if it is not working and include a full minimum reproducible example.